# Collapse .navbar and .dropdown-menu into hamburger menu, using BS4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4 and without Javascript, how can I create an arrangement like this when the viewport is large:

(nav items are floated left, user links are floated right)

[image]

And an arrangement like this when the viewport is constrained:

[image]

My current code looks like this ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/twgro2aq/)):

```
<div id="heading" class="row">
  <nav id='main_links' class="navbar navbar-toggleable col float-left" role='navigation'>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class='logo navbar-brand' href="/">
       <img src="http://www.boden.co.uk/client-catalogue/images/letterb-38.png" alt="B" />
    </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class='navbar-nav'>
        <li id="main_link2" class='nav-item'><a href="#" class='nav-link'>Item-2</a>
        <li id="main_link3" class='nav-item'><a href="#" class='nav-link'>Item-3</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

<div id="loginarea" class="float-right">
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="/profile/john" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">john@email.com</a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see from this code above, it doesn't collapse as desired when the viewport is constrained. How can I do it properly?

Comment: Can you put your code on JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) or Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) ? .. So other people can preview your code and the result as well

Comment: @RidoanSalehNasution Updated with a link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/twgro2aq/

Comment: If you want make it collapse, you'll need the Bootstrap JavaScript.